# Add a vertical line on half of semi doughnut chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, line, border

I need to add a vertical line (border) on half of semi doughnut chart, generated in Chart.js.

Now it looks that:
[image]

I need to it:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var myChart;
    function initializeChart(wyniki) {

        wyniki.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (b.komitet.rzad - a.komitet.rzad !== 0) {
                return b.komitet.rzad - a.komitet.rzad; // Sortuj malejąco po "Rzad"
            } else {
                return b.sumaMandatow - a.sumaMandatow; // Następnie sortuj malejąco po "SumaMandatow"
            }
        });

        var labels = wyniki.map(function (wynik) {
            return wynik.komitet.nazwa;
        });

        var goverments = wyniki.map(function (wynik) {
            return wynik.rzad;
        });


        var data = wyniki.map(function (wynik) {
            return wynik.sumaMandatow;
        });

        var colors = wyniki.map(function (wynik) {
            return wynik.komitet.kolor;
        });
        if (typeof myChart != 'undefined') {
            myChart.destroy();
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

        var chartData = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Podział mandatów',
                data: data,
                backgroundColor: colors,
                borderColor: "#131E3A",
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };
        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
                circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                    onClick: function (e, legendItem, legend) {
                        var clickedItem = wyniki.find(function (wynik) {
                            return wynik.komitet.nazwa === legendItem.text;
                        });

                        if (clickedItem) {

                        }

                        initializeChart(wyniki);
                    }
                },

            }
        });


    }

    // Wywołaj funkcję initializeChart na załadowanie strony
    window.addEventListener("load", initializeChart);
</script>
```

A parametr, which should determite a localization of added line, is var data. What'is important, I don't need to any action after clicking in this line. It should be only visible in good place.

I tried add someting to options, but - I won't hide - JavaScript is foreign language for me and I use to JS incidenatally.